# Sharing post from archive page (loop) doesn't work

Tags: posts, loop, facebook

On my archive page, I have for each post( I have include in the loop) the possibiity to share the post via facebook via this code:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<?php the_permalink();?>&t=<?php the_title(); ?>" target="blank">
<img width="50" heigh="50" src="http://mysite.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/fb1.png" alt="Facebook" /></a>
```

However, on click it allow me to share only the current page - and not the post . . .

Do you have any idea how can i fix this ?

Thank you for your time :)